What is "public" folder in Angular project?
I have generated a new Angular 18 project. I have noticed that it created a "public" folder instead of "src/assets", where does it come from?
It looks like this was used in previous versions and now it came back?
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1942
I would like to generate a new project that uses "src/assets" folder, is there a setting or a parameter I can use so that it's created automatically when generating a project or do I have to make the change manually after I generate the project?

Reading through the angular documentation it doesn't look like there's a parameter that you can pass to specify the assets folder path when using ng new
https://next.angular.io/cli/new
Luckily it shouldn't take much to change the assets folder once the project is created. All you have to do is:

move the public folder under src/

rename it into assets
1a. Alternatively delete the public folder and create the src/assets folder (since the folder only contains the favicon.ico file it shouldn't be a problem)

then change the assets value inside angular.json under architect => build and architect => test (that is, there should be 2 places where the public folder is mentioned in the angular.json file).
"assets": [
    {
       "glob": "**/*",
       "input": "src/assets"
    }
]



